# The program is not running after providing the input

Tags: c

This is a program from the book "C The Programming Language".

it is supposed to take an input and count the number of lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

When I run the program and provide an input it keeps adding newline after hitting Enter.

Comment: It's looking for EOF, so you have to close stdin. (Ctrl-D, I think).

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I hope you have at least the ANSI C version of this dusty old tome.

Comment: You'll need to end input, like CTRL+D or CTRL+Z depending on your OS.

Comment: You need to press ctrl+d on Linux/Mac or ctrl+z on an empty line in Windows to generate EOF and break the loop.

Comment: @tadman I don't even know what the ANSI is ? but, your solution is right Thank You!

Comment: It's an [obsolete C standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) a.k.a. C89 as in 1989 as in 34 years ago. There are [other books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that might cover newer C standards and have a lot fewer quirks than that book. Remember, that book was intended for compiler developers, not programmers per-se, and does a lot of *extremely* weird things to show off what C can do, not what you, as a programmer, should do.

Comment: @tadman I have the second edition

Comment: @tadman And I have another two books "C Programming absolute Beginners Guide" and "Head First C".

Comment: It's great you've got other resources. [This site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) offers a really great index of the various C functions available, or you can lean on `man` if your system has such a thing, as in `man strncat`.

Comment: Unrelated: The proper type for `c` is `int` so there's no need to make it `long`. Also, since you are counting newlines I don't expect that negative values will ever be needed so you could make `nl` `unsigned long` instead. Btw `%d` is not correct for `long`. It should be `%ld`

Comment: @TedLyngmo This code is from the 1980s where hair styles were different, MTV played music videos, and we liked our ints *long*. (K&R had some very strange opinions about what C should look like, didn't they?)

Comment: @tadman Ah...  back when I had hair :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hitting Enter key will give you a new line ('\n')

EOF is caused by a control + Z in Windows and control + D in Linux